# How to decrypt AES encrypted data with openssl command?

Tags: encryption, openssl

I want to decrypt AES encrypted data with openssl command.

- Encrypted data: `GD5YV2naJZ/x3mQnfictWQ==` (base64 encoded)
- Key: `uHe2MCmggLlugpGBiMVuXTck7OT8Nk8g`
- Cipher: AES-256-CBC
- IV: `LNP8U7pc6GjxzxAtgw4s3A==` (base64 encoded)

Comment: You might need to base64 decode it before decrypting it. The actual encrypted part is what's in "value" but you also need the IV. Bash won't do this automatically because this format seems Laravel specific

Comment: Decryption gives `s:4: "Test";`. In the OpenSSL statement, key and IV must be specified with `-K` (not `-k`) and `-iv` (both *hex* encoded). The input file must contain the *raw* ciphertext (for base64 encoding set `-base64`).

Comment: I have encrypted value in JSON. 
You can check full algorithm of decrypt and encrypt methods here
https://github.com/illuminate/encryption/blob/master/Encrypter.php

Comment: @Topaco can you explain, how i can do it, please?
Especially, I don't know how I can get this data from json and how I can get iv from json. I tried to use  ```encoded=$(echo "zyH5HS5tTN0xRFG+pM2uFA==" | openssl enc -base64 | od -t x1)```

Comment: @Topaco As I understand, you have the right answer. Can you share it with us in the answers?

Comment: i edited the question by removing most unrelated part.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Follow these steps:

```
$ echo GD5YV2naJZ/x3mQnfictWQ== | openssl base64 -d > data.enc
$ iv=$( echo LNP8U7pc6GjxzxAtgw4s3A== | openssl base64 -d | xxd -p | tr -d '\n' )
$ echo $iv
2cd3fc53ba5ce868f1cf102d830e2cdc
$ key=$( echo uHe2MCmggLlugpGBiMVuXTck7OT8Nk8g | xxd -p | tr -d '\n' )
$ echo $key
754865324d436d67674c6c7567704742694d56755854636b374f54384e6b38670a
$ openssl aes-256-cbc -d -in data.enc -K $key -iv $iv
s:4:"Test";
```

With `-base64` option, the decrypt command can directly use base64 encoded data as the input:

```
$ echo GD5YV2naJZ/x3mQnfictWQ== | openssl aes-256-cbc -d -base64 -K $key -iv $iv
s:4:"Test";
```

Comment: if you dont have `xxd` you can use other tools like `hexdump` to convert data to HEX strings.

Comment: Thanks @pynexj
How i can get Test, without s:4:".. ?

Comment: that's another different question. please ask a new one.

Comment: but i need to get data that i encrypted, I encrypted string "Test" and I want to get it. It's part of this question. 
How I can unserialize this string?

Comment: no. it's a totally different question.

Comment: Ok, i have new question for you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74387643/how-i-can-unserialize-string-by-bash

Comment: What i can do, if I have so long encrypted value like this and openssl cut it?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/249478/discussion-between-sinica-and-pynexj).

Answer (score 0):

Please follow the encryption and decryption of the string according to its [documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/encryption) and follow the step as well:

1. to decrypt a string use the following:

> ```
> Illuminate\Contracts\Encryption\DecryptException;
> use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Crypt;
>  
> try {
>     $decrypted = Crypt::decryptString($encryptedValue);
> } catch (DecryptException $e) {
>     //
> }
> ```

2. for encryption use:

> ```
> use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Crypt;
>
> Crypt::encryptString($request->token)
> ```

Comment: I need to decrypt it in the command line. It's part of the pipeline.