# How i can unserialize string by bash?

Tags: linux, bash, serialization, sh

I have a string `s:4:"Test";` from my [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74386133/how-to-decrypt-from-bash-string-that-was-encrypted-by-laravel).
How I can unserialize it and get just a `Test` string?

Comment: without knowing your exact string format it's nearly impossible to give a "correct" answer. try this: `echo 's:4:"Test";' | sed -e 's/.*"\(.*\)".*/\1/'`.

Comment: it's even not clear if you want to get `"Test"` (quoted) or `Test` (unquoted).

Comment: @pynexj `Test`
Thanks it's nice answer. Can you arr id to answers, I want to close this question

Comment: don't bother. you can post the answer if you like.

Comment: @pynexj Its dont work for multiline string.

Comment: There is no multiline string in your posting. You need to specify your exact input format if you want to receive a good solution.

Answer (score 2):

This will output *Test*:

```
str='s:4:"Test";' # Initial string
s=${str//[:0-9\";]/} # Remove digits, quote, colon, semicolon
echo ${s:1} # Drop the first character
```

Answer (score 0):

It works for me:

```
echo 's:4:"Test";' | sed -e 's/.*"\(.*\)".*/\1/'
```

But it don't works for multiline string